# Deformation of light-cone

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, visible-light, differential-geometry

In the paper *The geometry of free fall and light propagation* by Ehlers and his colleagues ([*Gen. Relativ. Gravit.* **44** no. 6, pp. 1587–1609 (2012)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s10714-012-1353-4)), when the authors introduce the differentiable structure on page 70, they claim:

> It should be realized that the representation of light in special relativity by means of ordinary cones rather than by hypersurfaces of hour-glass shape depends partly on a particular choice of differential structure.

The question is: What do they mean by saying **particular choice of differential structure**?
In what condition may the light cone be deformed and become like hour-glass as shown in this figure?

Thank you in advance for any help. 
[image]

Comment: With a metric $ds^2 = c^2dt^2 - dx^2$, the light cone $ds^2$ corresponds to $dx= \pm dt$. Now make the diffeomorphism $x = x_0 \ln y$, you have $ds^2 = c^2dt^2 - x_0^2 \frac{dy^2}{y^2}$, and the light cone is $dy = \pm  y \frac{cdt}{x_0}$, which gives you a "deformed" light-cone.

Comment: @Trimok thanks for your example,but diffeomorphism does not change the differentiable structure.

Comment: Oh I see. Yes, This has to do with the possibility of  different [differential structures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_structure) for the same manifold. This is maths then. I found a [paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/q-alg/9701026) which maybe gives an idea of what all this is about.